# How can I set indent 2 in Aquamacs?

Tags: configuration, indentation, aquamacs

The default indentation is 4 for tabs. How can I set it to 2 in Aquamacs? I see a configuration file `.emacs.d` in my home directory, but it doesn't look like the right file:

```
" ============================================================================
" Netrw Directory Listing                                        (netrw v140)
"   /Users/lucerne/.emacs.d
"   Sorted by      name
"   Sort sequence: [\/]$,\<core\%(\.\d\+\)\=\>,\.h$,\.c$,\.cpp$,*,\.o$,\.obj$,\.in
"   Quick Help: <F1>:help  -:go up dir  D:delete  R:rename  s:sort-by  x:exec
" ============================================================================
../                                                                               
~
```

Answer (score 0):

The customization option you are looking for might be:
    Top Level / Editing / Indent / Standard Indent

That is,
    Hit command comma or choose Options/Customize/Top-Level Customizations
    Click on Editing, then on Indent, then on Standard Indent
    Change the number to 2
    Click on "Save for Future Sessions"

Have fun!